# issue during update and creating a view

Tags: clearcase

I am getting this error during update and while creating a new view how to fix this

```
Unable to access "\S7P\f_error": database timed out.
1 config spec load rule problems encountered.
```

How would you troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

This should be linked to:

- either a network issue (as in [this thread](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=14634780), with a DNS issue, or with a samba path unavailable
- or a service issue (like the [`aldb_server` daemon](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21169395) not running anymore on the server, or a service on [your workstation](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21142584))

Comment: before it worked lot of times but from past 3 days if i am trying to update i am getting this error , i am using this on windows ,same view was created by other colleague on his pc he is able to work with it

Comment: @doppalapudisivakrishna did you try to reboot your workstation? Did your windows password changed recently?

Comment: @doppalapudisivakrishna Did you try to modify your load rules in the config spec in order to *avoid* loading `\S7P\f_error`?

Comment: nowi am able to update but i think that is not correct solution i had modified by removing f_error folder from load rules in the config spec is it correct to do

Comment: @doppalapudisivakrishna I completely agree that removing the loading rule is *not* the solution: I meant it simply as a debugging step. At this stage, you need to check the log on your workstation (`ccadminconsole.msc`), as well as the logs on the server in order to see any suspect error message (like in this thread, which isn't exactly about your case, but which is close: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=191719)